# hide div when click outside

Tags: javascript

I am using a simple javascript code to toggle div onclick. You can see it in action on this link: k-prim.biz/Untitled-2.html - it is a quite simple demo page. What I want to make is to hide div not only when click on the "link" but also when click outside the div. Also how can I change the css style of the "link" when the div is displayed? Thank you in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
   function showHide() {
   var ele = document.getElementById("showHideDiv");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
  }
else {
    ele.style.display = "block"; }
}
</script> 
<a href="#" onClick="return showHide();" >link</a>
<div id="showHideDiv" style="display:none;">hello!</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You've not given me any code to work with, so you'll have to modify this to suit your needs:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if(this != $("#the_div")[0]) {
        $("#the_div").hide();
    }
});
```

That will hide the div if a user clicks anywhere on the page that isn't that div.

Comment: Should be a closing bracket ")" at the end of that.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div id="settings">
<input/><select></select><span>text</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var settings = document.getElementById('settings');

document.onclick = function(e){

    var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
    var display = 'none';

    while (target.parentNode) {

        if (target == settings) {
            display ='block';
            break;
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

settings.style.display = display;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for presenting a vanilla code. It gave me the direction I needed. However, there is one error in that code. You need exit() instead of break. Break will only break you out of "while()" and will still set the display property to "none". Also, you do not need the "display = 'block'" inside the "if()".

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick hack I wrote. I am not sure why you want to do the same activity by clicking anywhere on the document. If you want to do that, replace jQuery('#link') with jQuery(document).

```
    <html>
        <head>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function(){
                  jQuery('#link').click(function(){
                       if(jQuery('#showHideDiv').hasClass('hide')) {
                          jQuery('#showHideDiv').removeClass('hide');
                          jQuery('#link').css('color', 'red');
                       } else {
                           jQuery('#showHideDiv').addClass('hide');
                           jQuery('#link').css('color', 'blue');
                       }
                    });            
                });
            </script>
        </head>
       <body>
            <a href="#" id="link" >link</a>
            <div id="showHideDiv" class="hide">hello!</div>    
       </body>
    </html>
```

This is the link to the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/EUScV/9/

and also add css rule

```
   .hide {
        display:none;
    }
```