# show and hide when clicked outside

Tags: javascript

I want to improve this script (ONLY WITH RAW JAVASCRIPT). It's a classic show / hide script (with onclick and classes). But when i show the div (.mini-list), the only way to hide it it's to click on the previous div ("Show me ya moves"). How to make a event listener that make this : when i click outside .mini-list, it's toogle the div if it's open. It's like every modal ever : close if we click outside.

I tested so many things, and all failed.

```js
function toogleClass(div, myclass) {
  var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + myclass + '\\b');
  var hasOne = div.className.match(regex);
  myclass = myclass.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  if (hasOne)
    div.className = div.className.replace(regex, '');
  else
    div.className = div.className + myclass;
}
```

```css
.mini-menu {cursor:pointer;}
.mini-show {}
.mini-list {display:none}
.mini-show .mini-list {display:block}
```

```html
<div class="mini-menu " onclick="toogleClass(this, 'mini-show')">Show me ya moves !
<div class="mini-list">Hi !</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652712/hide-div-when-click-outside

Comment: [Wheels: reinvented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)

Comment: You usually bind a click event to the body element and check if it's open or not. Not very efficient, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hide(e){
    if(e.target.parentElement === null){
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mini-menu")[0];
      if(document.getElementsByClassName("mini-show").length>0)
        toogleClass(x, 'mini-show');
      } 
}
document.onclick = hide;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to the document and close the div when user clicks outside `mini-menu`.

```js
function toggleClass() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  let div = document.getElementById('greeting');
  if (div.classList.contains('mini-list')) {
        div.classList.add('mini-show');
        div.classList.remove('mini-list');
    } else {
       div.classList.add('mini-list');
       div.classList.remove('mini-show');
    }
}

function closeGreeting() {
  let div = document.getElementById('greeting');
  div.classList.add('mini-list');
  div.classList.remove('mini-show');
}

document.getElementsByClassName('mini-menu')[0].addEventListener('click', toggleClass, false);
document.addEventListener('click',closeGreeting);
```

```css
.mini-menu {cursor:pointer;}
.mini-show {display:block}
.mini-list {display:none}
```

```html
<div class="mini-menu">Show me ya moves !
  <div id='greeting' class="mini-list">Hi !</div>
</div>
```