# Popup close when clicked outside div

Tags: javascript

I have a popup div onclick. The pop up works and the popup will not close when clicked inside of it. I found a code to close when clicked on the webpage but I do not know how to edit it.

Here is my code that works:

```js
function myFunction() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
// Prevents menu from closing when clicked inside 
        document.getElementById("myPopup").addEventListener('click', function (event) { 
            event.stopPropagation(); 
        });
```

```html
<span class="tooltip" onclick="myFunction()">
<div class="amount">$234.41</div>
<span class="tooltiptext" id="myPopup">This is how much money our community has raised to help provide meals and support to animal charities in our local communities.</span>
</span>
```

Here is the code to close when clicked outside the popup that I need help editing:

```js
// Closes the menu in the event of outside click 
        window.onclick = function(event) { 
            if (!event.target.matches('.dropbutton')) { 
              
                var dropdowns =  
                document.getElementsByClassName("dropdownmenu-content"); 
                  
                var i; 
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) { 
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i]; 
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) { 
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show'); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

Please if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hide div when click outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652712/hide-div-when-click-outside)

Answer (score 0):

I have this code that works to click on the page to close, only thing is I have 3 on the same page. Is it possible to remame it somehow. Thanks

```js
// Closes the menu in the event of outside click 
        window.onclick = function(event) { 
            if (!event.target.matches('.fa fa-trophy')) { 
              
                var dropdowns =  
                document.getElementsByClassName("tooltipstext"); 
                  
                var i; 
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) { 
                    var openmypopup = dropdowns[i]; 
                    if (openmypopup.classList.contains('show')) { 
                        openmypopup.classList.remove('show'); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
```